# Sync bitbucket branch with Openshift

Tags: git, openshift, githooks

How can I sync Bitbucket branch with `openshift:master` ?

I develop on my local desktop and I push my work into a branch named `bitbucket:uat`. Each time I push on `bitbucket:uat` I need after to run :
`git push openshift uat:master`

Is there a way to automatically push into `openshift:master` at the same time I push into `bitbucket:uat` ?

(I use Openshift v2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can push [to multiple remotes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/849308/6309), but since your remote branch name is different *pre* remote (and multiple `branch.<remote>.push` settings are probably not supported), an alias is the simplest approach.

```
[alias]
    pushall = "!f(){ git push bitbucket uat; git push openshift uat:master; };f"
```

Comment: Good idea yes thanks. Is it better to create a hook in bitbucket to pull in openshift from bitbucket automatically ?

Comment: A hook in bitbucket means a webhook, which isn't trivial to setup. I would go with the alias first, to test it out. Then, yes, a webhook is possible.